# Undefined method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting an error when trying to call a method in my controller. Following tutorials on how to get this to work but just a bit stuck in the mud and need some help.

```
NoMethodError in CatalogController#index
undefined method `art' for #<Class:0x007fbe8c338310>
```

My model

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/runs'
  # GET /feeds
  # GET /feeds.json
  def art
    response = self.class.get("/tnZ4F47Do9a7QeDnI6_8EKea/data?&format=json")
    @elements = response.parsed_response["image"]
    @parsed = @elements.collect { |e| e['url'] }
  end

end
```

My controller

```
class CatalogController < ApplicationController


    def index
      @images = Feed.art
    end


end
```

I'm guessing it's something fairly simple I'm forgetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def art` defines an instance method, not a class method.

You have two options to fix this problem:

1) Make the method a class method by adding `self.` to the definition:

```
def self.art
  # ...
```

2) Or create a `Feed` instance in your controller before calling `art`:

```
def index
  @images = Feed.new.art
end
```